# Driving a stepper motor with a sine wave

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, stepper-motor, stepper-driver, quadrature

I am attempting to drive a stepper motor where each phase draws 1 A at 3.5 V using a sine wave oscillator that outputs two signals 90° out of phase with one another.

At the outputs of this oscillator are op-amps, which put out the required 3.5 Vpp signals but don't provide much current.

What is the best way to boost these signals up to the required 1 A, and should I be worried about trying to implement any kind of current limiting?

Comment: Spend some time studying the idea of chopping current-mode stepper drive.  This certainly interacts with quasi-sinusoidal microstepping, but is conceptually distinct.  Needless to say, no one actually uses op-amps as the ultimate stepper driver, the actual drive has been switching for many decades now.

Answer (score 1):

The [TCA0372](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TCA0372-D.PDF) is a dual 1A power op-amp with reasonably  low saturation and Class AB low idle current. This might be suitable for your use or low power VFD control but better with PWM and current sensing.

But for micro-stepper-mode they use DRV8844 dual-H or Quad 1/2 H-bridge FET drivers with PWM control with an adjustable current limit to simulate analog quadrature sine voltage control. Get the whole boards. Low cost.